# Select an element with Jquery previously selected with Selenium 2 selector

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium WebElement selected, for example like this:

```
WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath('//div/span[@id='test']'));
```

If i have no knowledge about how i found this element, how can i select the same element with JQuery? All i have is the webDriver instance and the element instance.

Spoken in "pseudo-code", i want something like this:

```
webDriver.executeScript("$(" + element.getUniqueSelector() + ").attr('id', 'test2')");
```

/edit

I got my answer: [jQuery element selector with Id from Selenium 2 / WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614170/jquery-element-selector-with-id-from-selenium-2-webdriver/5626648#5626648)

Comment: This is basically the other direction to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5490523/675065

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer: [jQuery element selector with Id from Selenium 2 / WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614170/jquery-element-selector-with-id-from-selenium-2-webdriver/5626648#5626648)

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$(arguments[0]).whatever()", myElement)
```